# Installed 12.04, have no user interface, only the wallpaper backcground

Tags: upgrade, appearance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

I recently tried to update my desktop to 12.04- I was actually still using 9.10, so I've gone through the update process several times already, and this was the last one. I restarted, and it went to the log-in screen just fine, but when I log in, all I get is a the background image. There are no bars, no dock- I can right-click and do some settings menu stuff, but that is all. How can I fix, if possible?

Comment: Try to login in Unity 2D.
Is it login ok? If so then you have to search for video drivers.

Comment: Maybe this topic is of any help to you:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1606459 It contains information on how to start it from a command line interface, or when you're stuck. EDIT: This was linked to this issue:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears?lq=1 Might be worth checking that out, too.

Comment: The problem is I can't use the terminal either- I get it open but can't type on it. I also can't seem to log in through CTR ALT F1. Everything does work in Ubuntu 2d, though. 

Sorry for the duplicate question, I swear, I tried to check

Comment: You can select the recovery mode kernel in the boot menu (grub2) and drop to root shell. There you could try to fix your problem. Maybe purge and reinstall Unity?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Fossfreedom,
your question is similar to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears).
And [its answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/76951/32413) may be the answer you are expecting.

To confirm that the reason of the problem is the Unity installation,
before trying the solution of the similar question, you can try opening your session without Unity => with a **GNOME Classic (no effect)**:

- either when you chose your session
  [image]
- or if you are using an **auto login**:

  - <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>
  - login with your super user login
  - edit file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` (I personally edit using **vi**)
    and define `greeter-session=gnome-fallback`
  - `sudo reboot`